# Spring Gradle Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, bootrun

I working in spring project, I just got the project from my PM and when the project try to run got this error

```
Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved
```

The project is using more than one environment that using application.yml. So there'are some file similar like application-dev.yml etc.

And there's no specific error, I had no idea what the fu*k is this error.
Please help me if you know something about. thanks

You can check my build.gradle here

https://pastebin.com/3dwJAgNp

Comment: Can you please share you build.gradle file?

Comment: please check here @akortex https://pastebin.com/3dwJAgNp

Comment: How are you trying to run your project?

Comment: ./gradlew bootRun 

if with any profile
./gradlew bootRun -Penv=dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding mainClassName

mainClassName should be fully qualified class name, not path.

mainClassName = "full.package.name.MainClassApplication"

This official grade docs can be helpful .

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html